# Probability of Picking 3 Correct Digits on a 10,000 Combination Lock

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a combination lock question that's different from the other ones I've searched for here.  Here goes:

There's a combination lock that goes from 0000 to 9999. The correct combination is 1234.

What is the probability of guessing exactly 3 of the combination's actual digits (1,2,3,4), without regard for the guessed digits' order?  (For example, 341, 243, 412, 241, etc. would be acceptable 3-digit guesses).

My question is I'm not sure which approach to take. What I have so far (and I'm not even sure if it's right) is:

- For the first digit guess (which can range from 0 to 9), 4 digits are allowed (1,2,3 or 4), so: 4/10
- For the second digit, there are 3 choices are left (because we chose one from the set of 1,2,3,4 already), so 3/10
- For the third digit, there are 2 choices left (because we chose two from the set of 1,2,3,4 already), so 2/10.
- So, 4/10 x 3/10 x 2/10 = 3/125

Is this in the ballpark?  Thank you for any hints!

Comment: The same digit(s) might repeat; you might even be having the combination $0000$ ! Also, are you asking for **exactly** three digits correct or **at least** three digits correct ?

Comment: Hi @trueblueanil, good point. It's *exactly* 3 digits correct.

Comment: are you allowing spaces between the 3 correct digits. Also, just to clarify, are the same digits in a different order considered a different combination?

Comment: Hi @rviz, yes, space is allowed (e.g., 3,2,[ ],4). And no, digits in different order are considered same, since order doesn't matter as I understand it (312 = 123 = 231 = etc.)

Comment: If your question is: "A 3 digit sequence is selected at random.  What is the probability that it is one of the 24 sequences which share 3 digits with 1234?" then the answer is of course 24/1000=3/125.  Your method is absolutely fine too.  Are you sure that is your question though?  For example the second sentence of your comment above suggests that you are selecting unordered 3-tuples at random.  When you say a space is allowed, that suggests you are selecting ordered $4$-tuples.  All these things will affect the answer.

Comment: If the secret sequence is 1212, is there any winning sequence ? If the secret sequence is 1233, do you consider that 3314 is winning, or not ? Please illustrate with many examples.

Answer (score 4):

*Revised answer according to considered  interpretation of the question*

I have interpreted the question as " Suppose the lock has a $4$ digit code with $4$ *distinct* digits, say $1234$, unknown to me, what is the probability that I get **exactly** $3$ of the $4$ digits right, *even though the digits might be in wrong positions*, eg for $1234, 2138, 0432$
etc would be considered right.

Of the $10$ digits, $4$ are used, $6$ are not, so in order to get exactly $3$ digits right,

$Pr = \Large\frac{\binom43\binom61}{\binom{10}4} = \frac 4{35}$

Comment: This formula answers to another question : Probability to have exactly 3 digits 0 when we choose randomly 4 digits.

Comment: @tkf: Burning the mdnight oil is dangerous ! I have made the answer consistent with my interpretation,

Answer (score 2):

You can work step by step. First digit can be in 1,2,3,4 (P=0.4) or not (P=0.6)
Second digit can be in 1,2,3,4 and different from first one, or not.

After 2 digits, number of distincts digits in 1,2,3,4 can be 2 (P=0.12) or 1 (P=0.52) or 0 (P=0.36)

If number of distinct digits is 2, the 3rd digit can be in 1,2,3,4 , and different to first 2 ones (P=0.2), or it can not change the count of distinct digits (P=0.8)

Etc, etc

Final result : With 4 digits, you may have 4 distinct digits all in 1,2,3,4 : P=0.0024,

or 3 distincts digits in 1,2,3,4 (P=0.072)

or 2 distincts digits in 1,2,3,4 (P=0.354)

or 1 distinct digit in 1,2,3,4 (P=0.442)

or 0 distinct digit in 1,2,3,4 (P=0.1296)

Comment: It is not totally clear.  Option n°1 : what I have developped. Option n°2 : The actual combination is unknown, and I 'plaid' a combination, with 4 distincts digits. In this case, calculs are exactly the same. Option n°3 : the actual combination is unknown, what I have plaid is unknown (maybe 4 distincts digits, maybe less), and of course, calculs are different.

Comment: It says clearly "There's a combination lock that goes from 0000 to 9999. " And it has been clarified that you need to guess *exactly* $3$ digits correctly.

Comment: It says also clearly : The correct combination is 1234.

Comment: The correct combination is 1234 but it is taken to be unknown to us.

Comment: This is what I understood the question to be (+1).  However looking at the OP's attempt, it looks like they meant something different (see my comment to OP) in which case their answer is correct.  I suggest you also state the question you are answering before the answer, and provide a warning it may not be the OP's intended question.